# Appeal to reopen a question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I've asked [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50547/hard-data-on-all-seasons-vs-winter-tires) asking for hard data on comparison between all seasons and winter tires. I've received some feedback from the moderator about it being to general and I've addressed these concerns. Given that numerous other questions on this subject ([here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/all-weather-tires-vs-winter-tires-on-well-plowed-roads), [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/all-weather-tires-vs-winter-tires) and [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/49138/cheap-winter-tires-vs-high-quality-all-seasons)) seem on topic (and they are on at least the same level of broadness as mine) I think my question should be reopened.

The reason I'm asking the community for this is that even though a highly voted post exist, the question wasn't properly answered (the post is focused on anecdotal evidence, not on what the question asks) and needs more attention.

BTW.
I've left a comment explaining why the post doesn't answer the question IMHO, but for unknown reasons the comment has been deleted [image].

Comment: I've tried to introduce the tag [reopen-closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-closed) following SO, but I have not enough reputation :)

Comment: Why is this question getting down-voted? It seems to follow the correct process.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane - Please realize downvoting on Meta is not saying the question is a bad question, it means you disagree with what is being asked. The question is a valid question, but by voting it down, people are suggesting the question on the main site (as it's written) should not be reopened. If you feel it should be reopened, then an uptick is of course the right move. This is the OP asking the community ... the downvotes are saying the community doesn't agree.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is that your question was closed as being too broad - but you've not edited it to make it less broad - if you do so then I believe the system will automatically flag it for possible reopening and add it to the review queue.

In particular, I'd suggest narrowing down the environment you're interested in - I know from experience that winter in Poland is very different from winter in the UK, so the tyre requirements (and laws) are also different.

Of course, it may well be that the question is not answerable - there may not be any "hard data" studies other than the ADAC test you linked to.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I'll try to edit it again and make it even more focused :)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a mechanism in place for you to have the community vote as to whether your question is worthy of re-opening. Since you've been on SE for a few years, I'm sure you're already familiar with the process. I'm more than happy to see the outcome of your request to do so. By all means, click the [reopen](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50547/hard-data-on-all-seasons-vs-winter-tires#) tag which is at the bottom of the question with your pleas ... the community can then decide.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the process :) There is a reputation bar to vote to reopen a question, and as you may see it makes me not eligible to start the process on my own. Also, meta requests to reopen a question are not uncommon. Please refer to this explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question/36423

Comment: @BartoszKP - You only need [250 points to use the reopen link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) on your questions. If you can get to 250 points, then there are five people who agree with you and cast reopen votes themselves, I'm fine with allowing the question to be reopened. Or, if someone sees your request and clicks reopen for you, I'm fine with that as well.